# $_POST giving duplicate entries in array

Tags: php

I have a form like this

```
<input type = "text" name="name[]" value="1"> //row1
<input type = "text" name="name[]" value="2"> //row2
<input type = "text" name="name[]" value="3"> // row3
```

When I process the form in PHP, I get duplicate values in $_POST['name'] array.

```
print_r($_POST['name']);

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 3 [5] => 3
```

Row 1 time
Row 2 posting 2 times
Row 3 posting 3 times

Please help.

Edit::
Here is the complete code
http://pastebin.com/mYey5qcH

I am trying to print line 113. The field prqty[] is behaving as I mentioned in above example.

Solution:
I have fixed it myself, the issue was the append statement.
I used

```
tr.appendTo('#table_dest10');
```

instead of

```
('#table_dest10').append(tr);
```

Comment: Please show us the complete code or atleast the complte form

Comment: `<input type="name[]">`? Is that really your markup?

Comment: The code you provided [does not demonstrate the problem](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/26670636/) you describe.

Comment: Here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/mYey5qcH

I am trying to print line 113. The field prqty[] is behaving as I mentioned in above example.

Comment: You need to narrow your problem down yourself. Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Okay, I did some analysis and found out that the issue occurs when moving table rows across tables. When I place textbox manually on the destination table and submit the form, the output works. The issue is when I move the text control from one table to another, it duplicates.

Comment: Please update the question accordingly, especially make sure to include all relevant portions of code on this page.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="name[]" value="1"> //row1
<input type="name[]" value="2"> //row2
<input type="name[]" value="3"> // row3
```

this is wrong i think you are looking for this

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="1"> //row1
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="2"> //row2
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="3"> // row3
```

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text`. So you have just added more HTML for no effect.

Comment: Apologies, that was an typo... I have the correct markup like you mentioned above.

Comment: Here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/mYey5qcH

I am trying to print line 113. The field prqty[] is behaving as I mentioned in above example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="1"> //row1
```

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text`. So no, nothing has been forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it myself, the issue was the append statement. I used

```
tr.appendTo('#table_dest10');
```

instead of

```
('#table_dest10').append(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to define input type. Make it text then try again

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text`. So no, nothing has been forgotten.